# ffmpeg apply filters without rencoding?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to rotate a video using ffmpeg, but I don't want to lose quality by re-encoding.

If I try

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf 'vflip,hflip' -ss 120 -t 200 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```

No rotation gets preformed. If I instead specify the encoding by using, say `-c:v h264`, I'm afraid I'll lose some quality. Is there a "losssless" (relative to the original encoding) way of applying a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use a lossless encoder

Use of filters requires re-encoding. You can use a lossless encoder if quality is the most important factor:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf 'vflip,hflip' -ss 120 -t 200 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow \
-crf 0 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Using `-crf 0` when using `libx264` will create a lossless output but the file size may be very large.

#### Rotate upon playback

Rotating during playback will of course preserve the quality:

```
ffplay input.mp4 -vf hflip,vflip
```

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [How to flip a video 180° (vertical/upside down) with FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/578329/110524)